# Computer keeps turning on by itself after shutdown (not sleep)

Tags: bios, shutdown, wake-on-lan

I have activated Wake On Lan on the BIOS of my Alienware X51 R3 (2015) to be able to power it on from the internet and SSH into it. After trying the setup successfully, my pc keeps turning on by itself when I shut it down.

I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Elementary OS, and the behaviour is exactly the same independently of the OS where I power off from.

The strangest thing is that the computer will power on by itself even with the ethernet cable disconnected. I really don't know what is going on. If I deactivate WOL in the BIOS, everything goes back to normal, but with this setting activated, the pc will keep turning on a few seconds after the shutdown (not sleep), even without being connected to the ethernet cable.

Comment: Have you tried turning fast boot off from power options ?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/202830/why-would-my-computer-automatically-restart-after-shutdown-and-sleep